# How to fix Django project deployed in AWS EC2 but CSS and photos not working

Tags: python, css, django, image, amazon-web-services

I developed my project in localhost, everything is working. Then I pushed the project to github and finally cloned it in my AWS EC2 Ubuntu server. This is the sites public IP: http://3.16.1.224 . In the said public IP, all my contents is displaying, except for images and css. I tried to login into the admin panel but same, no css and images as well.

My folder structure is this:

```
jangooCMS
 accounts  /* an app for user creation */
 articles  /* an app for article creation */
 assets    
   logo-jangoo.png
 db.sqlite3
 jangooCMS  /* my main app */
   settings.py
   urls.py
   views.py
   wsgi.py
 manage.py
 media   /* all the articles images inside here */
   4-kitties-low.jpg
 requirements.txt
 templates
   base-layout.html

Now my base-layout.html have this on top:
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
```

---

Now going to my AWS, my settings.py is below:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets/")
```

Please help.. my first time to post here. Thank you!

this is the instruction I followed on deploying my project from github to AWS EC2:

```
cd Downloads/
mv blogoo.pem ~/Desktop/
cd ..
cd desktop

chmod

ssh

yes

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev nginx git

Y

sudo apt-get update
sudo pip3 install virtualenv 
git clone https://github.com/madonnadevt/jangooCMS.git
cd jangooCMS
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
pip3 install django bcrypt django-extensions
pip3 install gunicorn
cd jangooCMS
sudo vim settings.py


# Inside settings.py modify these lines allowed host public IP address I for INSERT

i


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['3.16.1.224']

# add the line below to the bottom of the file

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets/")

Save your changes and quit. ESC :wq

cd .. 
python manage.py collectstatic
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 jangooCMS.wsgi:application

ctrl+c

sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

i

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/jangooCMS
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/jangooCMS/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/jangooCMS/jangooCMS.sock jangooCMS.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

ESC :wq

deactivate

(directory should be in ubuntu)
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/jangooCMS

i

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 3.16.1.224;
  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location /static/ {
      root /home/ubuntu/jangooCMS;
  }
  location / {
      include proxy_params;
      proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/jangooCMS/jangooCMS.sock;
  }
}

ESC :wq

sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/jangooCMS /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo nginx -t
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Your website is requesting http://13.59.50.215/static/styles.css - note the `static/` path in there - and it does not find it. That is because you have declared the folder name as `assets` in your `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets/")
```

And in the nGinx config, you refer to it as `static/`

```
 location /static/ {
  root /home/ubuntu/jangooCMS;
 }
```

So, in order to fix it, is much preferred to use

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

Comment: thanks @foobarna! It works for my CSS and logo images which happen to be stored in static folder. But images from my media folder doesn't seem to work, these images I use for my article contents.. Please help.

Comment: In order for that to work, you need to make the process of uploading the images. You can't simply put them in "media" folder and work. If you want that, put them in the "asset" directory and run collect static, then use the URL with ".../static/my-img.png".